# How to send the "prints" of a script into a list without using "append", using python?

Tags: python, list

I would like to send all the "print" from my script into a list.
I have "functions" and also "loops".
You will notice that some ***"words"*** repeat, for example: Labels, Model, Image, Time(ms), Score, TPU_temp(°C).

I thought of using "append", but I need the ***"words"*** of each value as I will send them into a database.

MY CODE LOOKS LIKE THIS

```
def getInterpreter(root, files):
    for file in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(root, file)
        if filepath.endswith(".tflite"):
            print("Model:", file) <---------------------------HERE IS A PRINT
            print("\n") <--------------------------IT IS OKAY IF THIS GOES IN THE LIST 
            interpreter = make_interpreter(filepath)
            interpreter.allocate_tensors()
            return interpreter   
    return None



def getImage(dir_path, image_file):
    for file in image_file:#all files within the current path
         if re.match('.*\.jpg|.*\.bmp|.*\.png', file): 
                filepath = os.path.join(dir_path, file)
                print("Image:", file)   <-------------HERE IS A PRINT
                print("\n")         <------------ANOTHER PRINT
                return filepath
    return None


def main():
    subprocess.run('/usr/bin/snapshot', shell=False)           
    image_file = os.listdir(rootdir) 
    
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):          
        labels = getLabel(root, files)
        interpreter = getInterpreter(root, files)
       
        if interpreter is not None:
            size = classify.input_size(interpreter)

            for _ in range(count):
                start = time.perf_counter()
                interpreter.invoke()
                inference_time = time.perf_counter() - start
                classes = classify.get_output(interpreter, top_k, threshold)
                print('Time(ms):', '%.1f' % (inference_time * 1000)) <----ANOTHER PRINT!
            print("\n")                                  <--------------ANOTHER PRINT


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

THIS IS WHAT IS PRINTED AFTER EXECUTING MY SCRIPT

```
Labels: imagenet_labels.txt

Model: efficientnet-edgetpu-S_quant_edgetpu.tflite

Image: img0000.jpg

*The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model i                                                                                                             nto Edge TPU memory*
Time(ms): 23.1
Time(ms): 6.1


Inference: nematode, nematode worm, roundworm
Score: 0.02734

TPU_temp(°C): 61.55
#####################################

Labels: imagenet_labels.txt

Model: efficientnet-edgetpu-M_quant_edgetpu.tflite

Image: img0000.jpg

*The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model i                                                                                                             nto Edge TPU memory*
Time(ms): 28.9
Time(ms): 10.6


Inference: wall clock
Score: 0.01953

TPU_temp(°C): 61.55
#####################################
```

Comment: I’m sorry, I must be missing something. Why not append the list after each print statement.  What’s wrong with append?  You can write a utility function into which a string is passed and used for both printing and list appending.  This will provide a cleaner syntax.

Comment: Why? Why not just either return the data from the function and then use it at the callsite? It's possible to do what you want by inspecting the stdout, but really, that's a messy workaround for oddly-setup code.

Comment: Please add how the result list should look like.

Comment: I have added more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the issue but can you append to a list by wrapping up your multiple lines into one.

e.g.

**Joining into one line using append with an f string.**

> newlist.append(f'Model:{file}\n')

Let me know if I misunderstood your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect stdout of your script to a string buffer, so that the output of print functions would go into the buffer and then you can split the contents of the buffer based on newlines to get the output as list

```
from io import StringIO
import sys
import re

buffer = StringIO()
sys.stdout = buffer


# Your code should go here

stdout_lst = re.split(r'(?=\n)', buffer.getvalue())
```